# Nested Array Object Names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following `lodash` function with is grouping data and returning:

```
[
    {
        "tranid": "100",
        "trandate": "2019-08-20T07:00:00.000Z",
        "account": "1",
        "currency": "1",
        "departement": "1",
        "location": "1",
        "list": [ "1", "2" ]
    },
    {
        "tranid": "200",
        "trandate": "2019-08-20T07:00:00.000Z",
        "account": "1",
        "currency": "1",
        "departement": "1",
        "location": "1",
        "list": [ "3", "1260" ]
    }
]
```

However I'd really like to have it return:

```
[
    {
        "tranid": "100",
        "trandate": "8/20/2019",
        "account": "1",
        "currency": "1",
        "departement": "1",
        "location": "1",
        "list": [
            { "docnumber": "1" },
            { "docnumber": "2" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "tranid": "200",
        "trandate": "8/20/2019",
        "account": "1",
        "currency": "1",
        "departement": "1",
        "location": "1",
        "list": [
            { "docnumber": "3" },
            { "docnumber": "1260" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Specifically the part that I'm stuck on is how to make:

```
"list":["1","2"]
```

turn into

```
"list":[{"docnumber":"1"},{"docnumber":"2"}].
```

I know `list: _.map(v, 'docnumber')` in the group function needs to change but can't quite figure out how.  Any help would be great, thank you.

```
function group(data) {
  var group = lo(data).chain(data).groupBy("tranid").map(function(v,i) {
    return {
      tranid: i,
      processed: _.get(_.find(v, 'processed'), 'processed'),
      trandate: _.get(_.find(v, 'trandate'), 'trandate'),
      account: _.get(_.find(v, 'account'), 'account'),
      currency: _.get(_.find(v, 'currency'), 'currency'),
      departement: _.get(_.find(v, 'departement'), 'departement'),
      location: _.get(_.find(v, 'location'), 'location'),
      list: _.map(v, 'docnumber')
    }
  }).value();

  return group;
}
```

Comment: Sorry disregard the differences in the "trandate" between the current and desired output examples.

Comment: Also this is what the data looks like prior to the lodash group function.

Comment: [{"internalid":"1","tranid":"100","processed":false,"total":"2000000.00","trandate":"2019-08-20T07:00:00.000Z","account":"1","currency":"1","departement":"1","location":"1","dFormat":"M/D/YYYY","docnumber":"1","customer":"1141"},{"internalid":"2","tranid":"100","processed":false,"total":"300.00","trandate":"2019-08-20T07:00:00.000Z","account":"1","currency":"1","departement":"1","location":"1","dFormat":"M/D/YYYY","docnumber":"2","customer":"604"}]

Comment: so, **v** is an array(each group) and then you are doing **find** to get the first element and then taking the property? It seems you are doing it wrong as you will loss the subsequent object values for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the function in like so:

```
list: _.map(v, docnumber => ({ docnumber }));
```

This takes use of ES6 object notation shorthand. In vanilla JavaScript it would be:

```
list: v.map(docnumber => ({ docnumber }));
```

And in ES5, it would be:

```
list: v.map(function(n) {
  return {
    docnumber: n
  };
})
```